# How to report on a master-detail relationship

Tags: reporting, master-detail

I have a custom object named Milestones (with a field named MilestoneType) that has a Master-Detail relationship to Contact. I want to build a report where I can pull all contacts that have a milestone with a milestone_type of Deacon, but exclude those that also have a milestone_type of Retired. How do I build the report so that this conditions are met?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with Custom Report types (CRT). First, [create a custom report type](https://na1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/reports_defining_report_types.htm) for Contacts with Milestones by going to `My Name -> Setup -> Create -> Report Types`. Choose Contacts as the base object and then add a relationship for Milestones.

[image: Custom Report Type definition]

Create a new report based on the new CRT and you can filter on MilestoneType:

Unfiltered:
[image: Unfiltered report]

Filtered:
[image: Filtered report]

**Edit**
To show only Contacts who are Deacons and NOT retired we need to use cross-filters.

Unfiltered, showing updated Contacts. Note that the Contact "Second Test" has milestone types of both Deacon and Retired, while the other is just Deacon.
[image]

By setting a cross-filter of `Contacts without Milestones and Milestone Type equals Retired` we filter "Second Test".

[image]

Comment: first off ty. How would I report on all contacts that are deacons and that are NOT retired?

Answer (score 3):

Create two roll-up summaries on Contact. One that counts all milestones where type equals 'Deacon' and one that counts all milestones where type = 'Retired'.  Then report on all contacts where deacons > 0 and retired = 0.

I don't believe there is a way to directly build this in a report without adding these roll-ups on the contact.

Comment: @gringriforce I like this answer. I was also thinking about creating a trigger that would update a text field with a semi delimited string of all milestones. If I did it with a text field would I be able to report against it?

Comment: @fourq Yes, if you had a text (or multi-select picklist) field like Deacon;Retired;... you could definitely report against that but I would avoid  creating a trigger if you don't have to.

Comment: You can create the report with cross-filters.